# minimal distance betwen a point and and the halfspace containing a convex set

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $L^2(I)$ be the usual $L_2$ space with $L_2$ norm and $S$ a convex and  compact subset of $L^2(I)$. Suppose $g^*\notin S$ and

$$\min_{f\in S} \|f-g^*\|$$

has the unique solution $f^*\in S$.

Suppose a supporting hyperplane $H\subset L_2(I)$  supports $S$ at $f^*$ and $S\subset H^{-}$.

Would it be true that

$$\min_{f\in H^{-}\cup H} \|f-g^*\|$$

also has a solution $f^*$?

Here compact may refer  to weak compact.

Comment: It depends. $f^\ast$ minimises the distance in the closed half-space if and only if $(f^\ast - g^\ast) \in H^\perp$. If the supporting hyperplane is unique, that is the case. If there are several supporting hyperplanes at $f^\ast$, only one of them has $f^\ast$ as the closest point to $g^\ast$ in the half-space, all others have different closest points.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Is it possible to introduce some notion of smoothness for S in such space to ensure uniqueness?

Comment: In fact, in convex geometry the property that every boundary point has a unique supporting hyperplane is called exactly "smoothness".  (This notion is dual to strict convexity.)  Mathematicians outside of convex geometry might more usually say that the surface is differentiable.

Comment: By duality the distance to $S$ is going to be *maximum* of distances to all such $H$.